# A simple question about the application of the Bayes rule

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

I applied the Bayes rule as follows:

$$
P\left(\sum_{i=1}^N X_i>y|x<\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} X_i<y\right)=\frac{P\left(x<\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} X_i<y|\sum_{i=1}^N X_i>y\right)P\left(\sum_{i=1}^N X_i>y\right)}{P\left(x<\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} X_i<y\right)}
$$

Here $X$ is a random variable, $x<0$, and $y>0$ are some real numbers. My intention was to make the calculation of the left hand side easier because in its current form I need to make a convolution of the density of $\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} X_i$ with $X$ in the range $[x,y]$.

The two terms at the left hand side namely $P(\sum_{i=1}^N X_i>y)$ and, $P(x<\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} X_i<y)$ are easy to handle because the convolution is the regular one with the limits at $[-\infty,\infty]$.

I was thinking that the third term $P(x<\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} X_i<y|\sum_{i=1}^N X_i>y)$ would be equal to $1$. I was thinking that if the summation of $N$ terms was known to be larger than $y$, the sum of $N-1$ terms had to be in $[x,y]$, because otherwise the process would be terminated at the $(N-1)$th stage. I was wrong because the formulation doesnt have anything to do the with the procedure of terminating the process.

> **My question**: how can we calculate $P(x<\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} X_i<y|\sum_{i=1}^N X_i>y)$ in a simple way? is the right hand side (after applying Bayes to the left side) easier to calculate after all?

Thanks!

Comment: Is $N$ fixed or does it depend on the random variables? (You say that the process would be terminated at $N-1$, so it sounds like you want as much $X_i$ to get a sum less than $x$ or more than $y$.) Also, for a calculation, it would be useful to know the distribution of the $X_i$.

Comment: @Ragnar yes for all fixed $N$. The question is from squential test. $X_i$ are the log likelihood ratio increments $X_i=\log(f_1(Y_i)/f_0(Y_i))$ for the density functions $f_i$, $(i=0,1)$. I ran the process under $f_0$. For example let $f_0$ be Gaussian with mean $-1$ variance $1$ and $f_1$ be Gaussian with mean and variance $=1$. $x$ and $y$ are some thresholds as in the question. The process is terminated when $\sum X_i$ exceeds either $x$ or $y$ for the first time $N$. $N$ is here random but in the question, I evaluate for each single known $N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So... one considers two independent random variables $U$ and $V$ and the idea to compute $$(\ast)=P[U+V\gt y\mid x\lt U\lt y]
$$ would be to see whether $P[x\lt U\lt y\mid U+V\gt y]$ would not be simpler. I seriously doubt it is.

To compute $(\ast)$ when $U$ is densitable, consider the PDF $f_U$ of $U$, the CDF $F_U$ of $U$ and the complementary CDF $\bar F_V$ of $V$, then
$$
(\ast)=\frac{\displaystyle\int_x^y\bar F_V(y-u)f_U(u)\mathrm du}{\displaystyle\int_x^yf_U(u)\mathrm du}=\frac1{F_U(y)-F_U(x)}\int_x^y\bar F_V(y-u)f_U(u)\mathrm du.
$$

Comment: Do you have any idea about how to calculate $(**)$ without using the Bayes rule. For Gaussian replicas $U,V$, $N=2$, $P(x<U<y)$ is reduced from $0.47725$ to $0.299089$ when $U+V>y$ is known.

Comment: What is $(\ast\ast)$?

Comment: $P(x<U<y|U+V>y)$

Comment: Well, instead of dividing by $P[x<U<y]=F_U(y)-F_U(x)$ one should divide by $P[U+V>y]$, which is $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\bar F_V(y-u)f_U(u)\mathrm du$ and also $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\bar F_U(y-v)f_V(v)\mathrm dv$.

Comment: But the nominator is also about $U+V$ in your formulation, although here $P(x<U<y|U+V>y)$ it is about only $U$.

Comment: The numerator in P(x<U<y|U+V>y) must involve V since it is P(x<U<y,U+V>y), which involves (not only U but also) V.

Comment: Ok let me check it in mathematica. If it is so, then it is getting more complicated. I have convolutions for all $n=1,2,...N$ in the range $[x,y]$. I was only trying to get rid of these stupid convolutions. I cannot reach to any conclusions because I cannot get any analytical form when I get the integral of the error function. If no $[x,y]$ but $[-\infty,\infty]$ then I can get analytic forms easily even for the infinite sum (I guess).

Comment: No. Sorry I do not chat.